# Handsontable getCell empty on invisible cell

Tags: javascript, handsontable

When using handsontable's functionality to get the data of a cell:
`hot.getCell(2,2)` It normally will return the DOM element.

When using a table that is larger than the screen it will unload the data of the cells that are not visible even if you access them by their index.

I have added a fiddle below, where if you scroll right and then click the get value button it will fail to retrieve the data of the cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/JammyDodger231/x7dLwu6f/1/

Is this just a limitation to handson or is there an option to cache all results for access later without taking the functionality outside of handson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the available functions, there is an option to get the raw data from handson:

http://jsfiddle.net/JammyDodger231/syukz3uL/

```
hot.getData()[2][2]
```

By using `getData` with two array pointers it will retrieve the same data get `getCell` should